# Magento failure.phtml, get the order total

Tags: magento

One of the projects I work on has the failure page and success page in magento as exactly the same and requires some tracking code on both. The tracking code requires the order ID and the amount being ordered. The issue I'm having is trying to get the order total on the failure page.

The methods built into the block class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Failure` are `getRealOrderId()`, `getErrorMessage()` and `getContinueShoppingUrl()`, so no help there.

I found some code to do what I want on the success page but it doesn't work for the failure page.

```
<?php
$orderId = $this->getRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($orderId);
$_totalData = $order->getData();
$_grand = $_totalData['grand_total'];
?>
```

I dumped `$order` and `$_totalData`. `$_totalData` just an empty array and `$order` an empty `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` instance.

Does anyone have any suggestions for where to get the grand total of what is being purchased?

Regards,
Kieran

(I'm also having issues testing the success page as I can't get to it, even putting in the correct test card details on the dev server - but I'll find a way around this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order failed then there is no order to use, that seems sensible.

Perhaps, also, the cart hasn't been emptied in which case you can get the active totals with

```
$totals = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$grand = $totals['grand_total'];
```

Comment: I wasn't sure whether there would be an order created or not if the card verification fails. Reason being is that there is an order ID (`$this->getRealOrderId()`) so I wasn't sure. Being kicked out of the office now, but I'll try this in the morning, Thank you! :) Regards

Comment: The quickest way to find out would be to look at the `sales_flat_order` order table in the database. If a failed RealOrderId is present then you have your answer.

Comment: `$grand` returned a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total` instance and I just used `$grand->getValue()` and it worked fine. Thanks! :)